# Solving Poisson equation with Robin boundary condition with DSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I have the following BVP:
$-\Delta u = f \;\;\;\text{in}\;\Omega=(0,1)^{2}$

$u+\varepsilon\nabla u\cdot n = 0, \;\;\;\text{on}\;\partial\Omega$

where $f(x,y) = 2x(1-x) + 2y(1-y)$ and $\varepsilon>0$. I would like to use DSolve to obtain a solution but I'm not sure how to implement the BC, as all examples I've found so far only deal with pure Dirichlet or Neumann conditions. The Mathematica [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/PDEModelingAndAnalysis.html) states that NeumannCondition handles both Neumann and Robin BCs but I didn't see any examples that do it.

Comment: The first example in the `Scope` section of NeumannValue is a Robin bc (a generalized NeumannValue). Also note that your notion of the Robin bc is not quite correct: You needs the epsilon also in the equation or remove the epsilon from the Robin condition. See FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice#1529668360 that has an example of a DSolve and how it relates to NDSolve with Robin bcs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematica `DSolve` (V 12) can not solve this. You did not show your attempt. Here is what I tried.

```
ClearAll[x, y];
eps = 1;
L = 1; (*length of x side*)
H = 1; (*Length of y side*)
f = 2 x (1 - x) + 2 y (1 - y);
pde = -Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == f;
bc = {u[x, 0] + eps* Derivative[0, 1][u][x, 0] == 0,
   u[x, H] + eps* Derivative[0, 1][u][x, H] == 0,
   u[0, y] + eps* Derivative[1, 0][u][0, y] == 0,
   u[L, y] + eps* Derivative[1, 0][u][L, y] == 0
   };
DSolve[{pde, bc}, u[x, y], {x, y}, Assumptions -> {0 <= x <= L && 0 <= y <= H}]
```

But Maple 2019.2.1 can solve it

```
restart;
eps:=1;
L:=1;H:=1;
f:=2*x*(1 - x) + 2*y*(1 - y);
pde := diff(u(x,y),x$2)+diff(u(x,y),y$2)=-f;
bc:=u(x,0)+eps*D[2](u)(x,0)=0,
    u(x,H)+eps*D[2](u)(x,H)=0,
    u(0,y)+eps*D[1](u)(0,y)=0,
    u(L,y)+eps*D[1](u)(L,y)=0;
pdsolve([pde,bc],u(x,y)) assuming 0<=x , x<=L , 0<=y , y<=H
```

$$
u \left( x,y \right) =\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }4\,{\frac { \left( \pi\,n
\cos \left( n\pi\,x \right) -\sin \left( n\pi\,x \right)  \right) 
 \left(  \left(  \left( \pi\,n+1 \right) ^{2} \left( -1 \right) ^{n}+{
\pi}^{2}{n}^{2}-1 \right) {{\rm e}^{-\pi\,n \left( y-2 \right) }}-
 \left( \pi\,n+1 \right)  \left(  \left( \pi\, \left( {y}^{2}-y+1
 \right) n-2\,y+1 \right)  \left( -1 \right) ^{n}-\pi\, \left( {y}^{2}
-y-1 \right) n+2\,y-1 \right) {{\rm e}^{2\,\pi\,n}}+ \left(  \left( -
\pi\,n \left( -1 \right) ^{n}-\pi\,n+ \left( -1 \right) ^{n}-1
 \right) {{\rm e}^{n\pi\,y}}+ \left( \pi\, \left( {y}^{2}-y+1 \right) 
n+2\,y-1 \right)  \left( -1 \right) ^{n}-\pi\, \left( {y}^{2}-y-1
 \right) n-2\,y+1 \right)  \left( \pi\,n-1 \right)  \right) }{{n}^{3}{
\pi}^{3} \left( {\pi}^{4}{{\rm e}^{2\,\pi\,n}}{n}^{4}-{\pi}^{4}{n}^{4}
-{{\rm e}^{2\,\pi\,n}}+1 \right) }}
$$

[image]

Comment: I want to know why MMA's ability of solving partial differentiation is not as good as maple's and when it can reach Maple's computing power...

Comment: @PleaseCorrectGrammarMistakes you had better chose method by hand , run `?DSolve\`*` to see some undocumented functions.